# Which is faster abstract class or interface?

Tags: java, performance

*EDIT:*
**Note:** This is a interview question not a performance optimization process.

Please clarify my doubt:
Abstract class and interface implementation are having their own advantages but interms of performance which implementation is faster?

```
public class Client {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClsA obj = new ClsA();
    obj.display();

    InterfaceC obj1 = new ImplD();
    obj1.display();
  }
}
```

//I can call display() method in both ways as mentioned above. Which one give better performance?

```
public class ClsA extends AbstractB {
}

public class AbstractB {
  public void display() {
    System.out.println("---display---");
  }
}

public interface InterfaceC {
  public void display();
}

public class ImplD implements InterfaceC {
  @Override
  public void display() {
    System.out.println("---display ImplD---");
  }
}
```

In my understanding extending any class will leads lesser performance. Reason is if we are creating obj for sub class JVM also allocate memory for super class objects also.

But my friend said implementing any interface leads lesser performance. Reason is 
Here ( InterfaceC obj1 = new ImplD();) JVM has to find which is the implemented class is pointing to interface reference. So for look up will take sometime. But in extending other class JVM don't get any difficulty because linking between super class and sub class happens at compile time only.

Please tell me which one gives better performance?

Comment: I would say none, and it won't matter at all. This is a premature optimization and you should worry **only** if there's a problem in the application performance and it is demonstrated by usage of a profiler pointing to this abstract class or interface usage.

Comment: What did your profiler tell you after creating a test case and running it a few million times?

Comment: I do not think it is performance that matter to consider `interface` or `abstract class` to use, but in design pattern or practising strategy

Comment: *"This is a interview question not a performance optimization process."*  Sometimes questions are asked that way, where you are *expected* to reply 'neither'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Or "I honestly don't think it would make any real world performance difference, and it's more of a design decision, but I could certainly write a test case and *measure* it"

Comment: @BrianRoach  Agreed.  That is much more a 'hire this programmer' answer.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is categorically faster. Don't design your API based on your guesses about a performance tweak that almost certainly won't matter; use interfaces and abstract classes where they're conceptually appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In modern JRE, any performance difference between them are going to be very minuscule and probably going to be optimized away by the JIT if it matters. And no, I don't think there's even a performance difference in the first place in this case.

A wise man once said:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil